# JavaScript : array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I work on chat app with react js 
This is my array of object

```
const messages = [ 
  {message: "ghhhhhhhh", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: "10/1/2019 12:56"},
  {message: "ggggggghjjgcgh", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:45"},
  {message: "good afternoon", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:41"},
  {message: "hfdsghfdfhjo", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: " 10/1/2019 12:38"},
  {message: "hhhhhhhhhhhhh ", receiver: "harry", sender: "faty", time: " 10/1/2019 11:50"}
];
```

I want to display the last message between each person

I try the code below but he doesn't render what i want

```
    const senders =messages.reduce((a, c) => {
      a[c.sender] = a[c.sender] || { data: [] };
      a[c.sender].data.push({ sender: c.sender, message: c.message, time: c.time, receiver: c.receiver, hotel_id: c.hotel_id, isseen: c.isseen });
      a[c.sender].data.sort((a, b) =>{console.log(new Date(b.time),'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa');return ( new Date(b.time).getTime() - new Date(a.time).getTime())})
      return a;
    }, {})
    var messageInbox = Object.values(senders).map(s => s.data[0])
    console.log("Latest messages:", messageInbox);
```

---

this what I want to display :

```
  {message: "ghhhhhhhh", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: "10/1/2019 12:56"},
  {message: "ggggggghjjgcgh", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:45"}
```

let me explain I have two person faty and harry they have a lot of message between them i want to display the last message between them, the same between harry and marie

if you understand my problem please help me, thanks

Comment: Please provided expected output.

Comment: @BelminBedak ok

Comment: @BelminBedak i have explain please check the question

Comment: Sounds like you have *three* persons, including "marie"

Comment: @Dexygen yes i want to display messages between harry and faty / messages between harry and marie

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care whether a pair of recipients are a sender or receiver (so Hary could be the receiver/sender, and Faty vice versa) -- and it seems you *don't* care, based on your expected output -- then the code below should work.  First I sort the messages in *reverse* time order, because then when iterating with reduce, the first unique recipient combination will be the last message between them.

Then I make unique keys for recipient pairs, regardless of whether they are receiver or sender, by adding them to an array, sorting that array, and JSON stringify-ing it.  Sorting is what makes it such that you will get the last message between recipients, regardless of who was the receiver and who was the sender -- if you want two entries for Hary and Faty, one each for whether they are receiver or sender, then remove the sort.

If the object I'm returning on each iteration of reduce does not already have that key, I add the message using that key; if it *does* have that entry, I skip it as we already have the last message for that particular recipient pair.  Finally I call Object.values on the object returned by reduce.

The code is also at this repl: https://repl.it/@dexygen/lastMessagesBetweenRecipientPairs

```
messages.sort((a,b)=>{new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time)}); // reverse time order

const lastMessagesBetweenRecipientPairs = messages.reduce((lastMessages, msg) => {
    let key = JSON.stringify([msg.sender, msg.receiver].sort());
    if (!lastMessages[key]) lastMessages[key] = msg;
    return lastMessages;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(lastMessagesBetweenRecipientPairs));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ { message: 'ghhhhhhhh',
    receiver: 'faty',
    sender: 'harry',
    time: '10/1/2019 12:56' },
  { message: 'ggggggghjjgcgh',
    receiver: 'harry',
    sender: 'marie',
    time: ' 10/1/2019 12:45' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal can be achieved by simple actions:

- you can use `reduce` method to group by multiple keys such as `receiver` and `sender`
- after when your data is grouped then you can `sort` your `messages` by `time` property. The code looks like this `s.messages.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))`
- then you should just get the first item of array of `messages`. The code looks like this `...s.messages.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))[0] || ''`

So the whole code could looks like this:

```
let result = [...messages.reduce((r, o) => {    
  const key = o.receiver + '-' + o.sender;    
  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    messages: []
  });    
  item.messages.push({message: o.message, time: o.time});    
  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

result = result.map( s=> ({receiver: s.receiver, sender: s.sender, 
    ...s.messages.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))[0] || '' }))
```

An example:

```js
const messages = [ 
  {message: "ghhhhhhhh", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: "10/1/2019 12:56"},
  {message: "ggggggghjjgcgh", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:45"},
  {message: "good afternoon", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:41"},
  {message: "hfdsghfdfhjo", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: " 10/1/2019 12:38"},
  {message: "hhhhhhhhhhhhh ", receiver: "harry", sender: "faty", time: " 10/1/2019 11:50"}
];

let result = [...messages.reduce((r, o) => {
  const key = o.receiver + '-' + o.sender;
  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    messages: []
  });
  item.messages.push({message: o.message, time: o.time});
  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

result = result.map( s=> ({receiver: s.receiver, sender: s.sender, 
    ...s.messages.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))[0] || '' }))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not my Vote, but I'd guess it's because: 1. the Answer doesn't produce the requested result, 2. You don't explain anything. You just throw OP a bone by providing a snippet. 3. That's not nice nor self-explaining code; most certainly just gibberish for some newbie coming along reading this. And the one-character variable-names may be quick to use when you just scribble something, but not if you or someone else should ever come back to read this code. Maybe something along these lines could have been the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the great comment. I've edited my answer. In my view, it becomes clearer and better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below

```
 const messages = [
                {message: "ghhhhhhhh", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: "10/1/2019 12:56"},
                {message: "ggggggghjjgcgh", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:45"},
                {message: "good afternoon", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:41"},
                {message: "hfdsghfdfhjo", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: " 10/1/2019 12:38"},
                {message: "hhhhhhhhhhhhh ", receiver: "harry", sender: "faty", time: " 10/1/2019 11:50"}
            ];

            function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
                return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
                    var key = obj[property];
                    if (!acc[key]) {
                        acc[key] = [];
                    }
                    acc[key].push(obj);
                    return acc;
                }, {});
            }
            var messages1 = groupBy(messages, 'receiver');
            console.log(messages1); // get it in array with key as (harray or marie)
            var message2 = [];
            for(var k in messages1) {
                message2.push(messages1[k][0]); (// push them in simple array)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need latest messages for each couple, here's a function that checks for that. You get latest faty-to-harry, harry-to-faty and harry-to-marie.

```
 const getLatest = (messages) => {
  const hash = {};
  // Turns data into objects like this, to store which is latest:
  // {
  //   key: {
  //     time: timestamp,
  //     message: {}
  //   },
  // }

  for (let message of messages) {
    let sender = message.sender;
    let receiver = message.receiver;
    let time = message.time;

    let record = hash[`${sender}${receiver}`];
    if (record === undefined || new Date(record.time) > new Date(time)) {
      hash[`${sender}${receiver}`] = {};
      hash[`${sender}${receiver}`].time = time;
      hash[`${sender}${receiver}`].message = message;
    }
  }

  return Object.keys(hash).map(key => hash[key].message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

sort the elements by date then filter out based on the receiver or sender whoever you want, and pick the last one by `length-1` index:

```
  const lastMessage =
  messages[
    messages
      .sort((a, b) => {
        new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
      })
      .filter(el => el.sender === "faty" && el.receiver === "harry").length - 1
  ];
```

See it in action:

```js
const messages = [ 
  {message: "ghhhhhhhh", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: "10/1/2019 12:56"},
  {message: "ggggggghjjgcgh", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:45"},
  {message: "good afternoon", receiver: "harry", sender: "marie", time: " 10/1/2019 12:41"},
  {message: "hfdsghfdfhjo", receiver: "faty", sender: "harry", time: " 10/1/2019 12:38"},
  {message: "hhhhhhhhhhhhh ", receiver: "harry", sender: "faty", time: " 10/1/2019 11:50"}
];


const lastMessage =
  messages[
    messages
      .sort((a, b) => {
        new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
      })
      .filter(el => el.sender === "faty" && el.receiver === "harry").length - 1
  ];

console.log(lastMessage)
```

Comment: thanks for the response but you haven't understand my problem